# Построение графиков в C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, excel, c++

Можно ли в С++ Builder 6 построить график на основании определенных данных, чтобы не использовать Excel?

Или как-то можно в программе создать, открыть и записать в файл Excel информацию, которую выдаст программа, чтобы после в файле создался график с определенными параметрами?

Answer (score 2):

Построить график очень просто. Наверное что-то вроде

```
Canvas->MoveTo(StartX, StartY);
Canvas->LineTo(X, Y);
```

Excel понимает очень простой формат [CSV](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV). Напистаь выгрузку данных в такой формат совсем просто. А потом очень очень очень просто открыть такой файл в Excel и несколькими кликами мыши сделать график.

Answer (score 1):

А можно использовать COM-объект Excel. Придется познакомиться с типами OleVariant.

[Одно из простейших](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308407)

Answer (score 0):

Раньше был TChart. Простой способ нарисовать график.
Поиском находится на раз.